# mysql bulk SELECT with comparison conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a big ip_locations table with more than 2M rows. Given a specific ip, to select a ip_location record:

```
SELECT * FROM ip_locations WHERE ip >= start_ip and ip <= end_ip;
```

Now the problem is how to do this efficiently in a bulk select, given a ip array `[ip1, ip2, ip3, ...]. The size of the batch can be 1000+`. A simple way to do this could be

```
SELECT * FROM ip_locations WHERE (
   (ip1 >= start_ip and ip1 <= end_ip) ||
   (ip2 >= start_ip and ip2 <= end_ip) ||
   ....
);
```

But I am sure there should be more elegant and efficient ways to do this. In addition, how can I get each ip associated with the corresponding record in the batch select result?

Comment: Your solution looks good to me - that's how I'd do it. Try to keep your query size below 1 MB, we experienced problems with bigger queries in the past.

Comment: Create a table with those ips,index the column, JOIN on the main table

Comment: Are you sure want to take all the records that matches any one of the range?

Comment: @SridharDD there should be only one record matches one ip

Comment: @Mihai Do you mean to create a tmp table? Can you give more details with some sample codes? Thx!

Comment: @Yujun Wu:: What if you find min and max of all the batch and select all the records between the min and max?

Comment: @SridharDD did the query select all the records between min and max is also expesensive since it needs go through all the records any way?

Comment: @Yujun Wu:: Any way you have to select records by go through all. Since index is applied on your table and the column is of Integer type it will be much faster than you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to @Mihai idea, you could do this i.e. the following way:

```
SELECT 
    ip_locations.* 
FROM 
    ip_locations 
    INNER JOIN  
    (
     SELECT ip1 AS ip_to_check
     UNION 
     SELECT ip2 AS ip_to_check
     ....
     UNION 
     SELECT ipN AS ip_to_check
    ) AS ip_tab
      ON (ip_tab.ip_to_check >= ip_locations.start_ip 
         and ip_tab.ip_to_check <= ip_locations.end_ip)
```